# What is the PayPal REST API equivalent of Stripe Connect?

Tags: java, rest, paypal

Looking at the way " PayPal uses OAuth 2" (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/paypal-oauth2/), I don't see how using basic user name and password server integration can ever give me the ability to collect on behalf of over PayPal users.

Basically I want to be able to have a user with a PayPal account go through an access flow (ex. OAuth) which then gives me the ability to post payments to their accounts from customers.

This is what Stripe Connect does in a very easy straightforward way, does PayPal offer this in their REST API or in another developer API? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Login with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/identity/button/) or [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) / [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) (or a combination of both) might be what you're after.

Comment: It says in the docs: "Use the Preapproval API operation to set up an agreement between yourself and a sender for making payments on the sender's behalf." I want to collect payments on behalf of the PayPal merchant, will this handle that? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, as long as they've created a preapproval key with your app your app can then send payments on their behalf automatically without any further approval.

Comment: So if I want the user to do this one time where do they create the pre-approval key, is there a flow I send them through or do they do this inside the PayPal account? Thanks!

Comment: You send through a flow using the Preapproval API.